# How to completely delete navbar toggle button bootstrap asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to delete navbar toggle button from my ASP.NET site which is on BootStrap. I want to completely remove it, so when the browser window resizes, menu items should stay in their places.

P.S sorry for my English. Its my first question on Stack

Answer (score 0):

first of all when you re-sizes your window bootstrap give you proper response and hide your menu under the toggle button. now you want to remove this button and want you menu as it is so this is quite simple.

Step 1 : remove the toggle button code in page like :

Toggle navigation

remove this code

Step 2 : now remove the collapse class in the navbar div not the navbar-collapse remove the class collapse see below code

Home

About

Contact

after removing

Home

About

Contact

now you have done

Comment: I do that but when I resize my browser's window, it actually does something like this, please watch the video. That's my site. I have recorded to show you what it looks like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJ7tUXVz858